# Manipular dados entre variáveis enumeradas e "set of" no Delphi

Tags: android, delphi, variáveis

Tenho duas variáveis de tipos diferentes, mas dependentes, sendo que um tipo é um `set of` do outro tipo que é um `Enumerated Types`. Como faço para extrair o valor da variável do tipo `set of` (Y no meu caso abaixo) e atribuir à variável do tipo enumerado "X"? No meu exemplo, X teria que ser igual a "bcA", usando obrigatoriamente o "Y" para extrair o valor.
OBS.: programando em Delphi 10 com Android.

```
type
   TBaseCom_MODES = (bcA = 0, bcB = 1, bcN = 100);
   TBaseCom_MODES_Set = set of TBaseCom_MODES;

var X: TBaseCom_MODES;
    Y: TBaseCom_MODES_Set;
begin

   Y := [bcA, bcN];

   X := Y - [bcN]; // Aqui não funciona. Dá erro

end;
```

Comment: Qual o erro apresentado?

Comment: Isso que eu apresentei foi um exemplo de algo que eu gostaria que existisse (meu exemplo não é compilável). Tentei apresentar o que preciso que seja feito, para saber se alguém tem ideia de como resolver.

Comment: Ele não diz nem qual o erro de compilação dado?

Comment: Erro: "Tipos de dados incompatíveis". Se copiar o código e colar num evento qualquer do form, pressionando F9 aparecerá o erro.